# Initializing dynamically created redux-form field

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux-form

I have a redux-form Field which is dynamically created. For example, when I click on a button, I do a:

```
renderFormFields() {
 const r = someArray.map(s => {
   console.log(s.Value);
   return (<Field name={s.Name} type='number' component='input' min='1' {...s.Value} />);
 })

 {r}
}

render() {
 renderFormFields()
}
```

Now the `console.log` is printing the correct value for `s.Value` but the redux-form element is not having the correct value. The value is `empty` when the input Field is rendered. Any idea what I can do to initialize a redux-form Field when it is dynamically created ? (I cannot use the handleInitialize function approach that is mentioned in the documents as the form fields are dynamically generated at runtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Field`](http://redux-form.com/6.6.1/docs/api/Field.md/) component doesn't contain `value` prop. You can set the default values using couple of options:

1. `initialValues` (if you know the default values of fields that are going to be added dynamically)
2. Use [`this.props.change`](http://redux-form.com/6.6.1/docs/api/Props.md/) (if default values are also dynamic)

Modifed version of SimpleForm example from redux-form:

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'

const extendedFields = [{ name: 'City', value: 'Hyderabad' }, { name: 'Phone', value: 2 }];

class SimpleForm extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showExtended: false
    };
  }

  addExtendedFields() {
    // Not the best way to handle state. Doing this for simplicity
    this.setState({ showExtended: { initialized: false } });
  }

  renderExtendedFields() {
    const r = extendedFields.map(field => {
      return (
        <div key={field.name}>
          <label>{field.name}</label>
          <div>
            <Field type='text' component='input' {...field} value={field.value} />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return r;
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const { showExtended } = this.state;
    if (showExtended && !showExtended.initialized) {
      extendedFields.map(field => {
        this.props.change(field.name, field.value); // Option-2
        return field;
      });
      this.setState({ showExtended: { initialized: true } });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;
    const { showExtended } = this.state;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>First Name</label>
          <div>
            <Field name="firstName" component="input" type="text" placeholder="First Name" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <div>
            <Field name="lastName" component="input" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Email</label>
          <div>
            <Field name="email" component="input" type="email" placeholder="Email" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Sex</label>
          <div>
            <label><Field name="sex" component="input" type="radio" value="male" /> Male</label>
            <label><Field name="sex" component="input" type="radio" value="female" /> Female</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Favorite Color</label>
          <div>
            <Field name="favoriteColor" component="select">
              <option></option>
              <option value="ff0000">Red</option>
              <option value="00ff00">Green</option>
              <option value="0000ff">Blue</option>
            </Field>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="employed">Employed</label>
          <div>
            <Field name="employed" id="employed" component="input" type="checkbox" />
          </div>
        </div>
        {showExtended && this.renderExtendedFields()}
        <div>
          <label>Notes</label>
          <div>
            <Field name="notes" component="textarea" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div>
          <button type="submit" disabled={pristine || submitting}>Submit</button>
          <button type="button" disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={reset}>Clear Values</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={this.addExtendedFields.bind(this)} disabled={showExtended}>Show Extended fields</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

let HOCSimpleForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'simple'
})(SimpleForm);

HOCSimpleForm = connect(
  state => ({
    initialValues: { City: 'Test' } // Option-1
  })
)(HOCSimpleForm)

export default HOCSimpleForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be spreading 's' instead of s.value?

```
return (<Field name={s.Name} type='number' component='input' min='1' {...s} />);
```

Comment: s contains other fields too in addition to Name and Value, such as: s.Email, s.Phone etc. How will the spread operator know what value to choose for this field ? I probably should have used a different string than 'Value' in my code to explain clearly.

Comment: if you want to use only value, can't you set the prop directly value={s.value}

Comment: I did try that. Even for that, the initial value is empty. I mean, the console.log of s.value says 1 but the text box is empty.

Comment: btw, spread operator just expands all properties of the object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Answer (score 0):

Because you put s in string notation like this `'s.Name'`

You can put it like this {s.Name}

Comment: There is no problem with the name. I am getting the correct initial name for it. Yes, I need to use `{s.Name}` (the code in the question is wrong, I will fix it) but my question is for the initial "value" of the Field.